# How to hide a views result item based on role?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a View based on taxonomy vocabularies and terms. The view only contains 2 fields, `taxonomy vocabulary` and `taxonomy term` and the output is HTML list.

How can I hide **one of the terms** in one of the vocabs in the **view result** based on the role of the logged in user?

UPDATE:
With the help from No Sssweat below, this is how the final snippet looks like:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){
  global $user;
  if ($vars['view']->name == "view name" && strip_tags($vars['fields']{rendered_entity}->raw) == tid && in_array('user role', array_values($user->roles))){
    $vars['fields']{rendered_entity}->content = NULL;
  }
}
```

... in case anyone else need something like this snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you added `Taxonomy term: Name` as the field, which you want to hide.

Add this to your theme's **template.php** file.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

  $global user;

  if ($vars['view']->name == "name_of_view" && strip_tags($vars['fields']['name']->content) == "Term Name" && in_array('role name', array_values($user->roles))){
    $vars['fields']['name']->content = NULL;
  }

}
```

- change `mytheme` to your actual  theme name.
- change `name_of_view` to your view name.
- change `Term Name` to the name of the term.
- change `Role Name` to the specific role name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one thing... I am using Taxonomy term: Rendered taxonomy term... I am trying to figure out how to change your snippet but Devel refuse to show me the variables when I use dsm()... Could you enlighten me?

Comment: Never mind my comment, I just figured it out. Se my updated question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module as well.

> This module allows the admin account (user 1) to add fields, filters
>   and sorts to views which use PHP code. It also supports additional
>   accounts when the core PHP Filter module is enabled.

**While this module allows you to directly use PHP inside views which may be useful for quick and easy solutions, it is highly advisable to use regular handlers and plugins when available (or even to create one yourself). Take note that filtering and sorting a view using PHP always has a considerable perfomance impact.**

Steps:

Add Global PHP filter in view.
Load global user.
Get User role.
Get the term id
After getting both values, Put in condition.
 
If condition satisfy return False else return TRUE.